# When do you assign variables to 0 vs not assigning a variable to anything in c programming?

Tags: c, variables, variable-assignment

I am new to coding and in the process of learning C. I am taking some free courses and have a question about some of the activities. When assigning a variable when do you use a zero, one, or nothing at all? Examples below:

What is the difference between using a 0 or 1 in assigning a variable, both of these examples work, the first one is mine and the second one is the teachers, why did they use 1?:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
**int matches = 0;
int boxsize = 0;**
scanf("%d %d", &matches, & boxsize);
printf("%d\n", matches/boxsize);
printf("%d", matches%boxsize);
```

**OR**

```
**int matches = 1;
int boxsize = 1;**
scanf("%d %d", &matches, & boxsize);
printf("%d\n", matches/boxsize);
printf("%d", matches%boxsize);
```

**Other question**, this program worked both ways also. The first one is mine and the second one is teachers. Why assign a variable to zero? When should you not set a value to a variable at all?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
double kilometer;
double miles = 0.621371;
**double sum;**
int i;
scanf("%lf", &kilometer);
for(i=0;i<kilometer;i++){
sum = kilometer * miles;
}
printf("%.6lf", sum);
```

**OR**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
double kilometer;
double miles = 0.621371;
**double sum = 0;**
int i;
scanf("%lf", &kilometer);
for(i=0;i<kilometer;i++){
sum = kilometer * miles;
}
printf("%.6lf", sum);
```

Thank you for your help and if you have any ideas on resources for newbies to c programming let me know.

Comment: What's with the ** , that's not real code. use comments / or /*  */ ,If yo don not initialize a variable, its value at runtime is unknown and undefined behavior.  Could be 0, could be 234098, who knows.  Best to always initialize to a known value unless you know that it will get updated from a call to scanf, etc. before it it referenced.  Also, that for loop looks odd

Comment: @OldProgrammer, Yeah, those ** got me too :)  I think he meant to highlight the lines in question, and probably doesn't know yet that asterisks are used for pointers

Comment: The English grammar is the other way around: you can say "set a variable to a value", or "initialize a variable with a value", or "assign a value to a variable".

Comment: Thanks everyone, for your explanation, makes sense. For the **, I do know that it is not code. When I submitted it in the forum it was set to be bold to stand out better, but stackoverflow I guess left it as ** when I set it to code formate. Looking at the loop, I thought it seemed unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Both is valid.

From C99 standard, section 6.7.8 Initialization:

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized
> explicitly, its value is indeterminate.

If you do not initialize a variable, its value is unspecified.

Wether or not it makes sense to (not) initialize a variable depends on the code.

In your case, you explicitly assign values to the variables later after declaration and the initial value doesn't matter (`sum = ...` and `scanf("%d %d", &matches, & boxsize);`) so it doesn't matter too much here.
(Alltough, one might argue that `scanf` may fail and `matches` and `boxsize` still have an unspecified value after the `scanf` call).

Consider the following:

```
int sum;
for(int i; i < 500; i++){
    sum = sum + i;
}
```

If you don't initialize `i` and `sum` with an initial value of `0`, this most certainly will not do, what i want it to do, but still compile and execute just fine.

On the other hand, if i have for example a dedicated function to initialize my variable that is called right after declaration, or the initial value just doesn't matter at all, it may make sense to not initialize it at declaration.

Comment: The C standard makes a technical distinction between *unspecified* and *indeterminate*. As the text you quoted says, the value of an uninitialized object is indeterminate, not unspecified.